# String compare in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can anybody help me to do string compare(means not string to string as such, the values are fetched from object and stored in variable and comparing variable to variable, variable to variable) in the JavaScript.

```
    var val = findObject(":text1").text;
    var real = findObject(":text2").text;
    if (real.search(val) > 0) // if(real.indextOf(val) > -1) {
        test.log("Pass");
    }
    else {
        test.log("fail");
    }
```

Comment: check for equality can be performed by using either `==` or `===` operator. Do you mean equality check when you say `comparison`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve that by using the `===` operator

```
var val = findObject(":text1").text;
var real = findObject(":text2").text;
if (real === val) // if(real.indextOf(val) > -1)
{
    test.log("Pass");
}
else
{
    test.log("fail");
}
```

The `===` operator performs value as well as the type checking

Answer (score 0):

Just compare them as follows

```
if (val === real){
}
else 
{
}
```

If you know that both types are string you can also use '==' instead of '==='

Comment: I have tried this, but it is not working as it is expecting Objects to do the string operation.

Comment: try :-  if (val.valuOf() == real.valueOf())

Answer (score 0):

Checking for exact same values is made by:

1. When comparing only values

   ==
2. When comparing values and types

   ===
3. When you want to check if y is a substring inside x string.

   x.indexOf(y) > -1

I would recommend trim input before comparing (if that won't mess with business logic).
Like so:

```
var val = findObject(":text1").text.trim();
```

This will remove all not necesary spaces and white characters, that could be sometimes troublesome.

Comment: Here also it is not working as it is expecting string object than variable

Comment: Can you then explain us the problem in more detail? You asked about comparing 2 string literals, it doesn't matter their source, they are still strings. You want to check if real is equal to val yes? If not please explain and update your question.

Comment: Hi,It is working now after I convert the variable as String object.